# Buycraft ::before keeping from left

Tags: html, css, cm

I have a store [here](http://store.corinthmc.com)

*please excuse the dust. I am trying to get the logo to the left in header, but it looks like there is a div.header::before but it isn't in my css and I am assuming built in the cms somewhere. I have tried position: absolute; and also float: left; with no luck.

```
<div class="logo">
    {% if store.logo %}
        <a href="/"><img src="{{ store.logo }}" /></a>
    {% else %}
        <span>{{ store.name }}</span>
    {% endif %}
</div>

.container {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
```

}

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #333;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    border-bottom: 3px solid  #DAC896;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;

}
```

Comment: My temporary solution was to disable link to the default css - still curious if there is another way to actually fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you mixing all sort of different layout techniques together. I'm pretty sure you don't want to set the logo to `position: absolute`. This will position it relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

So you can get rid of it. In addition, you can also remove the `float: left`, since `floating` was invented to allow text to wrap around an image. It can be quite confusing since there was a time `floating` was used to create the whole layout.

But you don't need it at all, because you are using the browsers `native-grid`. Which is fantastic! Just be aware of the browser support: https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20grid

In your case you would need to specify the single `columns` of the grid. You can make use of the `grid-column` and `grid-row` properties. This looks like this:

```
.logo, .navbar, .buttons {
    grid-row: 1;
}

.logo {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.navbar {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.buttons {
    grid-column: 3 / 3;
}
```

You can learn more about the `native-grid` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: FAN-FREAKING-TASTIC -- much appreciated. I think this will help my other issue here also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310288/css-responsive-alignment-issues?noredirect=1#comment87636495_50310288